# Lock error (_wait_for_tstate_lock) in multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets

I create this two object Queue and PortScanner

```
class Queue(object):
    def __init__(self, queue=[]):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.queue = queue
        self.len = len(queue)
    def append(self, value):
        # Append value to the end of the list
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            self.queue.append(value)
            self.len += 1
        finally:
            self.lock.release()
    def pop(self):
        # Pop value from the end of the list
        self.lock.acquire()
        value = None
        try:
            value = self.queue.pop()
            self.len -= 1
        finally:
            self.lock.release()
        return value
    def getall(self):
        return self.queue

class PortScanner(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.qinit = Queue([20,21,22,23,24,25])
        self.qport = Queue([])
        self.host = host
    def check_port(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        port = self.qinit.pop()
        try:
            s.connect((self.host,port))
            s.close()
            self.qport.append(port)
        except:
            pass
    def check_multi_port(self, num_threads=2):
        for i in range(int(self.qinit.len / num_threads)):
            threads = [
                threading.Thread(target=self.check_port)
                for _ in range(num_threads)
            ]
            [t.start() for t in threads]
            [t.join() for t in threads]
        return self.qport.getall()
```

But it remains blocked until i press Ctrl+C and then get this error:

```
> ^CTraceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 156, in
> <module>
>     ports = scanner.check_multi_port()   File "test.py", line 144, in check_multi_port
>     [t.join() for t in threads]   File "test.py", line 144, in <listcomp>
>     [t.join() for t in threads]   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py",
> line 1056, in join
>     self._wait_for_tstate_lock()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py",
> line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
>     elif lock.acquire(block, timeout): KeyboardInterrupt ^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from
> '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py'>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py",
> line 1294, in _shutdown
>     t.join()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py",
> line 1056, in join
>     self._wait_for_tstate_lock()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py",
> line 1072, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
>     elif lock.acquire(block, timeout): KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Is that the full error traceback?  It looks like the final error message is missing.

Comment: added all errors

Comment: Looks like you have a recursive function:  `value = self.queue.pop()`.  You already have the lock then you try to acquire it again - deadlock.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm also running into this issue!

Comment: This often happens with long running threads using while loops and/or sleep()
Perhaps, unless you have cleanup tasks to do, you could set daemon to true so the threads exit when the main program exits

Comment: I don't know how to avoid this but to get out of the deadlock, you can 1) close the terminal window 2) Task Manager -> Performance -> Open Resource Monitor -> End `python.exe` process